# What can be the reason why artwork is not showing in the Sonos desktop controller for PC but it does in the Sonos desktop controller for Mac

Tags: sonos

My Sonos music service is rejected because artwork is blank on the desktop controller. However I have submitted png artwork in my service. I test my sonos music service on a Mac and the artwork shows up fine.

According to the digital asset guideline (http://musicpartners.sonos.com/?q=node/390):

> The Windows and MacOS controllers, and the Sonos CONTROL (cr200) are considered legacy controllers. These controllers still use images in PNG format. Therefore, you must submit your logos in PNG format as well.

Does anyone know the reason why the artwork is showing in the Mac desktop controller but not on the PC desktop controller?

```
<PresentationMap type="BrowseIconSizeMap">
    <Match>
        <browseIconSizeMap>
            <sizeEntry size="0" substitution="_legacy.png"/>
            <sizeEntry size="40" substitution="_40.svg"/>
            <sizeEntry size="290" substitution="_290.svg"/>
        </browseIconSizeMap>
    </Match>
</PresentationMap>

<PresentationMap type="ArtWorkSizeMap">
    <Match>
        <browseIconSizeMap>
            <sizeEntry size="0" substitution="_legacy.png"/>
            <sizeEntry size="40" substitution="_40.svg"/>
            <sizeEntry size="290" substitution="_290.svg"/>
        </browseIconSizeMap>
    </Match>
</PresentationMap>
```

Url browse icon

http://webservice.aristomusic.com/Sonos/static/images/menu/blue_legacy.png

http://webservice.aristomusic.com/Sonos/static/images/menu/blue_40.svg

http://webservice.aristomusic.com/Sonos/static/images/menu/blue_290.svg

Url artwork

http://webservice.aristomusic.com/Sonos/static/images/menu/orange_track_legacy.png

http://webservice.aristomusic.com/Sonos/static/images/menu/orange_track_40.svg

http://webservice.aristomusic.com/Sonos/static/images/menu/orange_track_290.svg

Comment: Could you post the contents of the 'ArtWorkSizeMap' (if you have) from the presentation map along with a couple of album-art URLs?

Comment: I edited my post with the info you asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your presentation map, you should be using `<imageSizeMap>` for `ArtWorkSizeMap` instead of `<browseIconSizeMap>`.

Also, note that the `ArtWorkSizeMap` is used for album art mapping whereas `BrowseIconSizeMap` is used for browse icon mapping. In your presentation map, they currently have same mappings.

- Implementing Album Art: http://musicpartners.sonos.com/?q=node/366
- Implementing Custom Browse Icons:
  http://musicpartners.sonos.com/?q=node/365

Comment: Okay, but what is the reason that this works on all devices and the mac desktop controller, but not on the windows controller? Because the way I've done it works on all other devices.